audit retention for library or content type or sensitivity label
I see options to assign audit retention policy for the entire tenant's sharePoint file operation or using PowerShell one site at the time.
I was asked to set a policy for one library across our thousands sites.
Is there a way to do it to a library? I can make a label or content type to these libraries. is there any way to apply audit retention per label or content type?
Thank you.
